# Is there a way to have 2 icons when using elixir-desktop?

Tags: elixir, wxwidgets, desktop

### Background

I have a personal project that is an elixir desktop application for PC Windows. It works pretty well, but now I want to give it an icon.

This is usually done in the following module:

```
defmodule WebInterface.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  alias Desktop
  alias Manager
  alias WebInterface.{Endpoint, Telemetry}
  alias WebInterface.Live.MenuBar

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      Telemetry,
      {Phoenix.PubSub, name: WebInterface.PubSub},
      Endpoint,
      Manager,
      {Desktop.Window,
       [
         app: :web_interface,
         id: WebInterface,
         title: "Market Manager",
         size: {900, 960},
         menubar: MenuBar,
         icon: "static/images/resized_logo_4.png", # THIS IS WHERE THE ICON IS SET
         url: &WebInterface.Endpoint.url/0
       ]}
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: WebInterface.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  @impl true
  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    WebInterface.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

### Problem

The issue here is that I have to use the same image for both the Windows taskbar and the top icon of the app:

[image]

The issue here is that while the logo on the bottom Windows bar (marked yellow) is nice, the one in the top is distorted and pretty horrible.

The fix to this would be to have an icon for the bottom and one for the top.
However after checking the [demo app](https://github.com/elixir-desktop/desktop-example-app) I didn't find a way of doing this.

### Question

Is this possible to achieve?  If so, how?

Comment: I think you need to build wx{Widgets,Python} from the latest release yourself in order to fix the icon blurriness.

Comment: My local machine has the latest downloadable version from the wxwidgets website (Latest Stable Release: 3.2.1). Are you suggesting this version is outdated?

Comment: what about wxPython? I don't know/remember what their latest release is based on...

Comment: I have not tried wxPython. To be honest, I am not sure of how wxPython and wxWidgets relate to each other. It's not like I can remove wxWidgets and install wxPython and then have everything working the way it used to.

Comment: Furthermore, this would also force my users to install Python on the local machines, and that is too much to ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

After asking in several places I was able to find some answers. In fact this post can be summarized in 2 questions:

1. Why are the icons so distorted?
2. Can I have an icon for the app different from the icon on the bottom bar?

---

### Why are the icons so distorted?

After checking with the official wxWidgets forums and getting help from the lovely folks there, I was pointed out that my icons did not confirm to the MSW standards for icons. In my case, these needed to be 32x32 or 16x16.

Research:

- https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_top_level_window.html#a33dc013a7cb33384f631b2764ca53b06
- https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=49813

### Can I have an icon for the app different from the icon on the bottom bar?

This one is a bit more tricky. There is a chance that using wxWidgets directly this could have been possible via the use of overlay icons. However, the library binding I use, elixir-desktop, does not support this, which means the icons need to be the same.

This is probably for the best, because as mentioned by the wxWidgets community, even such a use of overlay icons would not be standard amongst MSW applications, which is my case.

Research:

- https://elixirforum.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-have-2-icons-when-using-elixir-desktop/51621/3
- https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=49813

Answer (score 1):

At wxWidgets API level, you can specify icons in different sizes using `wxTopLevelWindow::SetIcons()` (notice the "s"), but I don't know if this function is available in Erlang bindings.

An alternative could be to use an icon from Windows resources but, again, not sure if you can use custom resources for an Erlang application.